# Column does not belong to table during populating DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When trying to populate datatable getting error Column 'ID' does not belong to table Employee.

```
namespace Demo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CreateTable ct = new CreateTable();
            CreateColumn column = new CreateColumn();
            column.CreateColumns();
            ct.AddRow("1","Dan White","UK","857495260","RandD","78954000");
            ct.AddRow("2","James","UK","7564210","Accounting","80000000");
            return View();
        }
    }
}

namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class CreateTable
    {
        private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("Employee");
        public void AddColumn(Type type,string name)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(name,type);
        }
        public void AddRow(string id,string name,string address, string phone, string department,string salary)
        {
            var row = dataTable.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = Int32.Parse(id);//Error in this line
            row["Name"] = name;
            row["Address"] = address;
            row["Phone"] = Int64.Parse(phone);
            row["Dept"] = department;
            row["Salary"] = salary;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }

    public class CreateColumn
    {
        public void CreateColumns()
        {
            CreateTable ct = new CreateTable();
            ct.AddColumn(typeof(Int32),"ID");
            ct.AddColumn(typeof(String),"Name");
            ct.AddColumn(typeof(String), "Address");
            ct.AddColumn(typeof(Int64),"Phone");
            ct.AddColumn(typeof(String),"Dept");
            ct.AddColumn(typeof(Decimal),"Salary");
        }
    }
}
```

(https://preview.ibb.co/h62OEn/Data_visvalizer_of_table.png) Data Visualizer after running CreateColumns()

(https://preview.ibb.co/g1AqS7/after.png) Data Visualizer during error

Comment: it seems you are creating columns for different table. not the same table you created earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `CreateColumns` method to take a parameter of type `CreateTable`:

```
public class CreateColumn
{
    public void CreateColumns(CreateTable ct)
    {
        ct.AddColumn(typeof(Int32),"ID");
        ct.AddColumn(typeof(String),"Name");
        ct.AddColumn(typeof(String), "Address");
        ct.AddColumn(typeof(Int64),"Phone");
        ct.AddColumn(typeof(String),"Dept");
        ct.AddColumn(typeof(Decimal),"Salary");
    }
}
```